# How to passing data between pages Reactjs with Hooks?

Tags: reactjs

I have an app for users but i can't transfer data between pages

my code in user files

```
function UsersView() {
    const [users - setUsers] = useUsers()
    const items = users.map((item, index) => {
        return (
                <Link to={{ pathname: `/users/:${item.userId}`, data: item }}key={index} ">
                    <p> {item.userName}</p>
              </Link >
)
    });
    return (
        <div>{items}</div>
    )
}

export default UsersView
```

in user details page

i try to use this

```
function userDetails(props) {
    const history = props
    console.log(history);

    const { data } = useLocation();
    // const { data } = props.location
    console.log(data);
   return (
        <div></div>
    )
}
export default userDetails
```

my package.json is

```
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-router": "^6.0.0-beta.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.0",
```

could you please give me solution

Answer (score 0):

use this as the link:

```
<Link to={{
  pathname: '/users/:${item.userId}',
  state: {
    data: item
  }
}}><p> {item.userName}</p></Link>
```

and then access it like this:

```
const { state: { data } } = useLocation();
```

Comment: Do anyone give me a solution please?

Comment: It's gave me {state: null}